# Java webpage from a java class or method

Tags: java, javascript

Say I have a java class with a method in that class which returns an integer. Now I want to have a webpage (Eg. HTML page) which would access this class and then method and display the result.

how do I do this? What do i learn to do it? first of all what's this called? servlet? applet? what?

Sorry. I know basic java.. but new to this thing...

Comment: [JavaServer Pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages)

Comment: the thing you want is web developement , learn to HOW TO MAKE FIRST WEB APPLICATION , btw i would suggest start making your first servlet

Answer (score 1):

Web means HTTP; HTTP means servlet.  You need a servlet and a servlet/JSP engine like Tomcat.

You need a Web archive (WAR) to package your app and deploy it to the servlet/JSP engine.

Your .class will go in the WEB-INF/classes folder of the WAR, along with the servlet .class file.   Be sure to put everything into a package.

You'll need a web.xml in your WAR.

Take a look at [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/index.html) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for Java Platform, Enterprise Edition.

From Oracle

> Java Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) 6 is the industry standard
>   for enterprise Java computing. Utilize the new, lightweight Java EE 6
>   Web Profile to create next-generation web applications, and the full
>   power of the Java EE 6 platform for enterprise applications.
>   Developers will benefit from productivity improvements with more
>   annotations, more POJOs, simplified packaging, and less XML
>   configuration.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html

Answer (score 0):

OK, Start like this

- What is HTML?
- What is HTTP?
- What is a web server?
- How browser communicates with a web server [lets say google.com]?
- What is Tomcat and how I can install apache tomcat in my machine?
- What is Servlet and how can I create one?[download required jars like servlet.jar]
- What is a jar, war?
- How to create a war.
- What is Eclipse?
- How to create a webproject in Eclipse?
- Create a web project using internet tutorials[search for 'simple
  servet example java']
- What is web.xml?
- What are build scripts?
- How to deploy a java servlet  code to tomcat server?